# Trying to optimize pyqtgraph plotting

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I am trying to draw polygons without the use of pg.PolyLineROI() in pyqtgraph.  My goal is to be able to use large data sets in place of "data" in the code shown below.  My issue with PolyLineROI() is that I do not need the handles or the events, so loading large amounts of data takes a long period of time and resources that are just wasted on unneeded functionality.

I have tried using QPainter and QPen but I have not been able to get anything that works so I am stuck.  Any ideas?

*EDITED Code trying to incorporate example from segFaultCoder*

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys

class plotwindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

            self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
            MainWindow.resize(1900, 1000)

            self.qt = pg.GraphicsView(MainWindow)
            self.qt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0,0, 1900, 1000))
            self.qt2 = pg.GraphicsLayout()
            self.qt.setCentralItem(self.qt2)
            self.qt.show()
            self.layout = self.qt2.addLayout()
            self.qt3 = self.layout.addViewBox()


            self.plot()

        def plot(self): #This is looped for multiple data sets
            data = [[6,6],[6,0],[0,6],[0,0]] #changes based on data import
            self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
            p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
            p.setPen(pg.mkPen('w'))
            self.points = []
            for item in data:
                point = QtCore.QPoint(item[0], item[1])
                self.points.append(point)
            p.drawPolygon(*self.points)
            p.end()
            self.qt3.addItem(p)

    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.picture.boundingRect())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = plotwindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were on the right track with QPainter, just looking at their examples folder you'll see a customGraphicsItem.py.  I basically just copied that and replaced their "data" variable with your points, and then rewrote the generatePicture() method using a QPainter.drawPolygon().  Hopefully all my indents are right, I can't quite get the hang of formatting posts on SO.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph import QtCore, QtGui

# Create a subclass of GraphicsObject.
# The only required methods are paint() and boundingRect() 
# (see QGraphicsItem documentation)
class customPolyItem(pg.GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, data):
        pg.GraphicsObject.__init__(self)
        self.data = data  
        self.points = []
        self.generatePicture()


    def generatePicture(self):
        # pre-computing a QPicture object allows paint() to run much more quickly, 
        # rather than re-drawing the shapes every time.
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen('w'))
        for item in self.data:
            point = QtCore.QPoint(item[0],item[1])
            self.points.append(point)
        p.drawPolygon(*self.points)
        p.end()

    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)

    def boundingRect(self):
        # boundingRect _must_ indicate the entire area that will be drawn on
        # or else we will get artifacts and possibly crashing.
        # (in this case, QPicture does all the work of computing the bouning rect for us)
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.picture.boundingRect())

data = [[6,6],[6,0],[0,6],[0,0]]

item = customPolyItem(data)
plt = pg.plot()
plt.addItem(item)
plt.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: customPolyItem')

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Edit: regarding your new code, replace your plot method with this (and remove paint and boundingrect):

```
    def plot(self): #This is looped for multiple data sets
        data = [[6,6],[6,0],[0,6],[0,0]] #changes based on data import
        newCPI = customPolyItem(data) # create new instance with changed data
        self.qt3.addItem(newCPI) # add the new instance to your viewbox
```

You will need to import the customPolyItem class if it's in a separate file, or just copy paste the whole class declaration below your current plotwindow class.

Comment: I am stuck trying to implement your code into my loop.  I have edited my code above to represent where I currently am at.  I get the same error with my edited code above as I do with calling your class in my code also so I am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: just looked closer at your code.  Notice in the comments above my example, "customPolyItem" that it subclasses GraphicsObject, and as referenced there as well, 'paint' and 'boundingrect' are method overrides of 'QGraphicsObject -> QGraphicsItem' methods.  In your code, you can't now use these two methods in a 'QMainWindow' subclass.  For each new set of "data", you need to create an instance of customPolyItem and add it to your plots/layouts accordingly, and in that scenario, customPolyItem still owns the paint and boundingrect methods.

Comment: See my edited answer, and be sure to accept as answered if it works :)

Comment: I tried exactly what you have and when plotting large data sets, it cuts out most of the data and just plots multiple squares when placed in a separate file and called into my code.  I set data to a data set containing 30 points and it drew one rectangle.

Comment: since I don't fully know what you're trying to accomplish, i can't solve that problem. if you can post the code that's not working, and explain what you would "like" it to do, i'd be glad to try and help.  I certainly can't test boundary conditions for you without better details. did you get it to work with the 4 point example you posted?  if so, at what point does it break?

Comment: Yep, thanks for your help.  I ended up using GraphItem() to build the objects and as long as build the entire structure of my array before I call addItem(), it has very good performance.